# How to call a batch file from batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need the syntax to call a batch file from the first batch file. The second batch files name changes with the revision. so i have only half of my second batch file name.

How do i search in a particular folder and call the second batch file..`?

Comment: You can use `call bat_file_2.bat` in `bat_file_1`

Comment: @2-Stroker i can use that if i know the complete name of my second batch file. But here, the batch file name changes with revision, so i cant use it. I want to search with bat_file*.bat and then call. I dont know how to do it

Comment: There is no way to answer this question. How are we supposed to know what is the current version? There could be any number of batch files in the folder that match the "first half". How are we to know which one to run? Be specific as to the rules. What is the "first half"? What are the rules as to how to identify the correct "second half"? How are the "halves" put together to form a complete file name?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the revision prefix or suffix, but you could try something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%n in ('dir /on /l /b /a-d "bat_file_*.bat"') do set latest_bat_file=%%n
```

It's relying on dir /on to sort by name, so it puts the last entry alphabetically in the variable %latest_bat_file%. You can then call it with:

```
call "%latest_bat_file%"
```

This assumes there are no spaces in your bat file names and that the revision is a numeric or alphabetical suffix. If you're using numbers, to avoid sorting problems, prefix your revision names with zero's (e.g. bat_file_001, bat_file_002).

Comment: as an alternative you can sort not by name (`/on`) but by date (`/od`), assuming newer versions have newer timestamps (eventually `/t` can help also). See `dir /?`

Answer (score 0):

`FOR /R <path>` will walk the directory tree for you.

```
FOR /R "%DIR_TO_SEARCH%" %%b IN (matching_*.bat) DO cmd /c "%%~b"
```

`cmd /c` will create a new shell instance, which means that if the invoked .BAT file sets environment variables, they won't be changed in calling script. This is usually what people want. If you actually **wanted** those side effects preserved, you could use `call "%%~b"` instead.